# Error on running multiple select query apache derby

Tags: java, derby

I am not able to run code below with multiple select query. I am able to run queries below individually but I want to run all together and store their results in ArrayList. Error I get is `java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet not open. Operation 'next' not permitted. Verify that autocommit is off.`

Any advice? or is there a better way to do this? Thanks

```
public ArrayList<String> getTotalCountBasicQueries() {

        ArrayList<String> totalCount = new ArrayList();
            Statement stmt = null;

            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            try {

                String q1 = "select count query";
                String q2 = "select count query2";
                String q3 = "select count query3 ";

                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(q1);
                ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(q2);
                ResultSet rs3 = stmt.executeQuery(q3);

                while (rs.next()) {
                    totalBasicCount.add(rs.getString(1));
                }

                while (rs2.next()) {
                    totalCount.add(rs2.getString(1));
                }
                while (rs3.next()) {
                    totalCount.add(rs3.getString(1));
                }


                rs.close();
                rs2.close();
                rs3.close();
                stmt.close();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("Table fetch failed or result data failed");
            } finally {
                if (stmt != null) {
                    try {
                        stmt.close();
                        System.out.println("Could not close query");
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Could not close query");
                    }
                }

                return totalBasicCount;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

See the javadoc for `ResultSet` :

> A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object
>   that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next
>   result from a sequence of multiple results.

you can't have multiple resultset open for a unique statement, per spec. however, some jdbc driver allow this

try :

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(q1);
while (rs.next()) {
   totalBasicCount.add(rs.getString(1));
}
ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(q2);
while (rs2.next()) {
   totalCount.add(rs2.getString(1));
}
ResultSet rs3 = stmt.executeQuery(q3);
while (rs3.next()) {
   totalCount.add(rs3.getString(1));
}
```